# install and uninstall tensorflow from environment

Tags: python3, cuda

I installed the gpu tensorflow with conda with environment tensorflow

```
source activate tensorflow
```

I try to reinstall it with cuda-10 and tensorflow 2.0 
but the previous version keep conflict with net version 
so I want to remove all tensorflow from environment

I uninstall it with

```
pip uninstall tensorflow 
conda remove tensorflow
```

but it keep import it 
import tensorflow has no problem
How do I check all tensorflow installed and remove it ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably had confusion between tensorflow-gpu and tensorflow.
Try the following process:

1. Change to your environment `source activate tensorflow`.
2. Run `pip freeze` to check which packages are installed.
3. If you find tensorflow-gpu (or tensorflow) installed, run `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu` and `conda remove tensorflow-gpu`.

If it does not work, deactivate your environment and do the same process again.